# Remove subsection header in the document, keep it in the TOC

Tags: pdf, pdfpages, header

How can I remove the subsection header in the document (over the PDF file in this case), but still have the header in TOC?

Code:

```latex
\includepdf[pages=1,pagecommand=\subsection{Header1} \thispagestyle{empty}]{xx.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=2-,pagecommand=]{xx.pdf}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `\subsection{Header1}` but instead use

```latex
\refstepcounter{subsection}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}
  {%
    \ifnum2>\value{secnumdepth}\else\protect\numberline{\thesubsection}\fi Header1%
  }
```

Complete MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[]{article}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{something}
\refstepcounter{subsection}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}
  {%
    \ifnum2>\value{secnumdepth}\else\protect\numberline{\thesubsection}\fi Header1%
  }
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

One could as well create a macro that does take two arguments, the sectioning level and the heading and create a TOC entry without typesetting a heading, if this is needed multiple times. The following should work for the standard classes.

```latex
\usepackage{pdftexcmds}
\makeatletter
\def\@getsecnum@fin#1\else#2\fi{\fi#1}
\def\@getsecnum@none\fi{\fi1000}
\newcommand*\@getsecnum@a[2]
  {%
    \fi\ifnum\pdf@strcmp{#1}{#2}=0 \@getsecnum@fin
  }
\newcommand*\@getsecnum[1]
  {%
    \ifnum\pdf@strcmp{#1}{part}=0 \@getsecnum@fin{-1}%
    \else\@getsecnum@a{#1}{chapter}{0}%
    \else\@getsecnum@a{#1}{section}{1}%
    \else\@getsecnum@a{#1}{subsection}{2}%
    \else\@getsecnum@a{#1}{subsubsection}{3}%
    \else\@getsecnum@a{#1}{paragraph}{4}%
    \else\@getsecnum@a{#1}{subparagraph}{5}%
    \else\@getsecnum@none
    \fi
  }
\newcommand\TOConlySection@[3]
  {%
    \ifnum#1>\c@secnumdepth
    \else
      \refstepcounter{#2}%
    \fi
    \addcontentsline{toc}{#2}
      {%
        \ifnum#1>\c@secnumdepth
        \else
          \ifnum#1=-1
            \thepart\hspace{1em}%
          \else
            \protect\numberline{\csname the#2\endcsname}%
          \fi
        \fi
        #3%
      }%
  }
\newcommand\TOConlySection[2]
  {%
    \expandafter\TOConlySection@\expandafter
      {\romannumeral-`0\@getsecnum{#1}}{#1}{#2}%
  }
```

Usage would be

```latex
\TOConlySection{part}{part heading}
\TOConlySection{section}{section heading}
\TOConlySection{subsection}{subsection heading}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is needed for the included pdf, then you can use option  `addtotoc={⟨page number ⟩,⟨section ⟩,⟨level ⟩,⟨heading ⟩,⟨label ⟩}` for `\includepdf`.

```latex
addtotoc={1,subsection,2,<heading>,<label>}
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{A section}
See subsection~\ref{subsec:H1} on page \pageref{subsec:H1}.
\includepdf[pages=-,addtotoc={1,subsection,2,Header1,subsec:H1}]{dummy}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]